# How to search or filter an array of data via GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have been using queries in graphql to match and filter on strings.  While matching directly on strings is simple (see account_name below*),* matching on an array of strings (see employee_names below) appears to be a challenge.

```
account_name: acme_co, 
employee_names: [
   john_smith,
   mark_tom,
   kelly_clark
]
```

I'd like to do something like the below query where I am returning the accounts in which a certain employee_name is matched

```
 query MyQuery {  
   employee_info(limit: 10, where: {employee_name: {_eq: "mark_tom"}}) {     
      account_name   
   } 
}
```

I realize this query doesn't work because I am trying to match a string to an array but use this as an example of what I'm trying to accomplish because the variations I have tried don't work and I have yet to find a way to filter an array of strings to match a string in a direct equal or like query like I might directly on a string.

Is there a simple way to implement this in graphql, or would it be better to have the query return all records via my graphql query and then let the web client filter the data down to employee names in the array?

I've tried variations of filters but my query is never able to successfully resolve.  Searching through other stackoverflow links has been ambiguous.  I saw an older post from many years ago in which someone ultimately decided to let the web client handle the filter stating that this was not possible in graphql but I am not sure if things have changed since then.